# Segue to Master Detail Controller from Table View Controller

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I am try to connect a TableView Controller to a Master/Detail View Controller but I'm getting this error when connect with a show segue.

```
Split View Controllers cannot be pushed to a Navigation Controller
<UINavigationController: 0x7fe913011c00>.
```

Do I connect the segue to the Master View?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to connect to the Master View. After connecting to the same. It will resolve this issue.